# Value of type 'Messaging' has no member 'token'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this method to access the token (FireBaseCloudMessasing)  in my VC instead of storing it in the AppDelegate but I got this error : Value of type 'Messaging' has no member 'token'

```
func getFCM(){
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching FCM registration token: (error)")
          } else if let token = token {
            print("FCM registration token: (token)")
            self.fcmRegTokenMessage.text  = "Remote FCM registration token: (token)"
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to update dependencies.
If you use Cocopoads, update Firebase/Messaging pod to the latest version with

```
$ pod update Firebase/Messaging
```

or if you want to update all the pods use

```
$ pod update
```

Worked for me

Comment: Worked for me. I am using capacitor and did expect this is managing everything for me. but not in this case. It updated a lot of stuff. After running the first command i got another error about a missing file but after running the second everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you `FirebaseMessaging` pod is too old.

Updating it should fix it:

```bash
pod update
```

On Apple Silicon I had to do this instead:

```bash
arch -x86_64 pod update
```